# How to write one to many relationship query in C# linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, one-to-many

How can I write a query in linq, that expresses a one to many relationship.
I have this class:

```cs
public class Author
{
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("books_ids")]
        public ICollection<ObjectId> Book_Ids { get; set; }
}
```

I want my query to retrieve all books where Book.Id is in Book_Ids, how do I go about writing it?

Comment: What is `Book.Id` ?

Comment: Try the `SelectMany` function.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Book is a class that has .Id, it is an ObjectId property.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: As Voigt mentioned:, SelectMany projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable<T> and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence. [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
private IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksForAuthor(Author author, IEnumerable<Book> allBooks)
{
      return allBooks.Where(book => author.Book_Ids.Contains(book.Id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to the answer to what I was looking for! But, it is a bit annoying there isn't a way to express finding the author, and getting all the books, without adding a foreign key to the Book class.

Comment: If you don't have a foreign key, how will you relate book and author? If you think this has to be duplicated at all places where you try to fetch books for an author, maybe add it as this as a public method on Author class itself. This allows everyone to use the same operation.